# multy upload /modified type= file with jquery

Tags: jquery, file, upload

i wonder if thre any solution to modified type="file" with jquery. i've tried to figured out how is work, but have no luck.
if someone can help me, or giving an idea how it work, i'll be so thanksfully.
this ist my Code:

```
 $(function(){

function getFile(){
    $('.uploadbutton').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('.upload').find('input[type="file"]').click().on('change', function(){
            var $that = $(this),
                value = $that.val();

            if($(this).id = 'docupload'){
                $('#docupload').val(value.replace(/00040E-/i, ''));
            }
            if($(this).id = 'pdfupload'){
                $('#pdfupload').val(value.replace(/00040E-/i, ''));
            }
            //$that.closest('.input_text').val(value.replace(/00040E-/i, ''));

        })
    });
}

getFile();
```

})

and this is my html:

```
<div class="upload">
    <input class="input_text" id="docupload" placeholder="upload sample files" readonly="" type="text">
    <div class="uploadbutton">upload doc</div>
    <div style='height: 0px;width: 0px; overflow:hidden;'>
        <input id="upfile" type="file" value="upload"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="upload">
    <input class="input_text" id="pdfupload" placeholder="upload sample files" readonly="" type="text">
    <div class="uploadbutton">upload pdf</div>
    <div style='height: 0px;width: 0px; overflow:hidden;'>
        <input id="upfile" type="file" value="upload"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should explain what is your expected behaviour

Comment: @Wolff, thank you very much for the quick response. i've try to modified type=file with jquery. and every <div class="uploadbutton">upload pdf / anything else</div> should do the right job. for the moment if i click first button, it giving me (responding ) for all input type back.